# WP user agent returns random variables

Tags: globals, browser-compatibility

I am using a PHP function in order to return the user browser, using the WP global variables.

It used to work perfectly, but recently it started doing random things on Safari.
I use chrome and everything is fine at home.
My colleague uses Safari and depending on the test, he has different results.

On sidebar.php :

```
<div class="sidebar s2 <?php echo 's2_'.detecter_user_agent(); ?>">
```

In functions.php :

```
function detecter_user_agent() {
$cl = '';
global $is_lynx, $is_gecko, $is_IE, $is_opera, $is_NS4, $is_safari, $is_chrome, $is_macIE, $is_winIE;

if($is_lynx) $cl = 'lynx';
elseif($is_gecko) $cl = 'gecko';
elseif($is_opera) $cl = 'opera';
elseif($is_NS4) $cl = 'ns4';
elseif($is_safari) $cl = 'safari';
elseif($is_chrome) $cl = 'chrome';
elseif($is_IE) $cl = 'ie';
elseif($is_macIE) $cl = 'macie';
elseif($is_winIE) $cl = 'winie';
else $cl = 'unknown';

return $cl;
```

}

This is the code to generate a CSS class for the right sidebar on https://blog.defi-ecologique.com

When my colleague tries it, it sometimes returns s2_chrome, s2_gecko or even s2_unknown.

I have no way of knowing how many of my readers have this issue.

Could you please help me make sure that the right global variable is returned at any time ?

Thank you !

Comment: it is a bad idea to do browser detection on server side. insert your classes with JS

Comment: +1 @MarkKaplun, I think this question just highlights how unreliable server side browser sniffing can be.

Comment: Thank you, I will try. would you have a good tutorial to suggest ?

Answer (score 1):

You can examine [`wp-includes/vars.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/vars.php) for specific logic which implements sniffing for these globals in WordPress.

In a nutshell the checks are very basic, especially considering user agent sniffing is inherently a mess.

If you need a more reliable implementation you would have to get one elsewhere (or code it yourself). That or use different technique entirely, such as detecting necessary context client–side with JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, every time I tried with JS I have been failing miserably. How would you proceed ? Would you have a tutorial to suggest ?

Comment: Not my area of expertise, sorry.